# Computing starting and ending date labels for each week in a month in PowerBI PowerQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

[image]I have data regarding dates in a fact table in PowerBI. See the attached sample, DateFactTable, for 10/2021 (October 2021). A week starts on a Sunday. Note that 10/2021 has 6 weeks and weeks 1 and 6 are split across two months; week 1 has only 2 days and week 6 haenter image description heres only 1 day in October. I would like to compute labels in PowerQuery for each day of the month and put them in a separate column for this fact table. See the attached "Expected Output" pdf for the expected output; note the outlined column called "Week Label" that I would like to add. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I dont see any expected output

Comment: Trouble uploading a pdf and had to convert to an image. Please check now. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Powerquery / M

Make sure date column is a type date

Right click Week of Month and group by, accept all default options and hit ok

Change ending of code in code window from

```
, {"Week of Month"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
```

to

```
, {"Week of Month"}, {{"Data", each _, type table}, {"Label", each Text.From(List.Min([Date])) & "-" &  Text.From(List.Max([Date]))}})
```

use arrows atop data column to expand the date, day name, day of week and week of year columns

add column, custom column with formula

=   "Week "&Text.From([Week of Month])&": "&[Label]

remove extra column

full sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Week of Month"}, {{"Data", each _, type table}, {"Label", each Text.From(List.Min([Date])) & "-" &  Text.From(List.Max([Date]))}}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Data", {"Date", "Day Name", "Day of Week", "Week of Year"}, {"Date", "Day Name", "Day of Week", "Week of Year"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Data", "Custom", each "Week "&Text.From([Week of Month])&": "&[Label]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Label"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the aggregation function and computing the min and max dates for each group and then used these dates to compute the labels.